# Can I change an XPC Service's quality of service level?

Tags: macos, cocoa, xpc

I am looking to put an XPC service in place in my app, which would need to process user input (that it receives from a separate process) instantaneously.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/power_efficiency_guidelines_osx/PrioritizeWorkAtTheTaskLevel.html) for QOS states:

> In an XPC service, the main thread runs at a QoS of default

I would need to be able to set the XPC service thread to have a QoS of `user-interactive` to be sure the user input events to ensure this occurs.

Is it possible to change the QoS of an XPC service's thread?

I understand that I could create a daemon and set the task policy using an approach such as the below:

```
struct task_qos_policy qosinfo;

memset(&qosinfo, 0, sizeof(qosinfo));
qosinfo.task_latency_qos_tier = LATENCY_QOS_TIER_0;
qosinfo.task_throughput_qos_tier = THROUGHPUT_QOS_TIER_0;

task_policy_set(mach_task_self(),
                  TASK_BASE_QOS_POLICY,
                  &qosinfo,
                  TASK_QOS_POLICY_COUNT);
```

Would doing something like this, say in the main method of an XPC service, be a possible and appropriate way of achieving this?

I could of course create a daemon, but I'm currently investigating ways to make my architecture work with sandboxing so I can distribute through the Mac App Store.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Comment: Here's someone with a similar problem: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682769. Unfortunately, no answers at this point.

Answer (score 1):

We were having a problem where performance in our XPC service was way worse than running the same code in our application. After banging our heads against the wall for a few days, we finally found a clue in the "Context Switches" section of the "System Trace" instrument. Some of our threads would have "blocked" entries looking like this:

```
00:09.911.098   Preempted at priority 4 for 32.44 ms because thread was taken off CPU temporarily to cool the processor and surrounding hardware.
```

A 33ms stall is pretty bad in our scenario. Luckily, I found a very simple workaround. It seems that the XPC service will have it's QoS level elevated as long as there are XPC reply blocks that have not been invoked.

So the workaround looks like this:

1. At startup, send a message from the application to the XPC service. The message should include an XPC reply block.
2. When the XPC service gets the message, retain the reply block, but do not invoke it.

In my setup, this keeps the XPC service at a higher priority level so we don't get preempted as aggressively. This was on macOS 11.6.